# Greedy approach for single solution problem

Tags: greedy

Can we use greedy approach for **non-optimal**, **single solution** problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking if you can use the greedy approach to solve a problem that does not have the optimal substructure property, the short answer is no, not really. Let me explain:

- Greedy algorithms basically take all of the data in a problem and then set a rule they use to determine which data to add to the solution during every step of this algorithm (essentially, the greedy technique picks the locally optimal data to add to the solution in the hopes it results in a globally optimal solution).

  - A problem having the optimal substructure property means that a (globally) optimal solution can be built from the (locally) optimal solutions of its subproblems.
  - Considering that this property is essentially the key for what the greedy approach does, I would say it would be a bad idea to use the greedy approach for a "non-optimal, single solution" problem. I hope this helps!